# Independent Desktops for Windows Virtual Desktops

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

For example: Virtual desktops independent across monitors. Right now If I switch virtual desktop on monitor A it also switches on monitor B.

I just want it how it is on Linux and Mac OS. If I switch virtual desktops it should only switch on one monitor.

I am looking for a way to access these three features by Keyboard
 shortcut

- Independent virtual desktops
- Send an app to virtual desktop 2 and follow
- Restrict an app to a virtual desktop or show on all Desktops.

Thanks

Comment: You want something that simply isn't possible with Virtual Desktops.  Windows has never treated the desktops the way Linux has.  The only way to make it possible is to extend the base feature with a third-party application.